# jQuery - How to use an HTML string as a control element

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery DataTables table that contains `<input ...` fields. Based on user input on the same page I need to make a few changes to the attributes of the `<input ...`. The field has an id attribute, but it is unknown at the time this attribute change needs to be made.

Using DataTables API I have found the row index containing the input field. I also know the column and so I am able to retrieve the input field like this:

```
var inputfield = $('#oTable').DataTable().cell(row, column).data();
```

This results in `inputfield` containing a string:

```
<input value="0" id="someid" color="red" size="large" type="text">
```

I would like to use jQuery to access the attributes of this control something like this:

```
inputfield.attr("color", "black");
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a simple way of taking an HTML string and using it as though it was a control field accessed like this:

```
var inputfield = $('#someid');
inputfield.attr("color", "black");
```

Is there an easier way of doing this other than parsing as a plain string?

**EDIT**

As stated, I'm using jQuery DataTables and performing a search for all table rows containing a color attribute with a value of red:

```
var color = "red";
rows = dpTable.fnFindCellRowIndexes('color="' + color + '"');
```

Rows is an array containing the indices of rows containing `color="red"` and this works. An example returned value for is `rows = [2, 5, 12]`

Now I want to change a few attributes of the `<input ...` fields on the cells of each row. So I do this:

```
$.each(rows, function (index, value) {
    var inputfield = $('#oTable').DataTable().cell(value, 1).data();
    var newHtml = $(inputfield);
    newHtml.attr("color", "TEST");
    alert($(newHtml).attr("color"));
});
```

The `alert()` above returns `TEST` as desired, but the control field in the DataTables doesn't get updated. So I need to convert `newHtml` back to a string, use DataTables API to replace the cell contents and then use DataTables .draw() function to update the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the attributes of the variable like this http://jsfiddle.net/0tag89yf/1/

```
var inputfield = '<input value="0" id="someid" color="red" size="large" type="text">';
var newHTML = $(inputfield);

var color = newHTML.attr('color');

alert(color);
```

Comment: How would I then switch newHTML back to a string? I'm using DataTables and the attribute isn't changing. I must have to place the string back in the table cell and issue a draw().

Comment: Do you want to change the color attribute? What is draw()? You are asking how to access the attributes and this is a way of doing it. Please be more specific what you want to do

Comment: I am changing the value of a cell in jQuery DataTables. The value of inputfield is a string because DataTables returns it via search API. I needed to change some of the attributes and then put it back in the DataTables cell as a string. I see your jsfiddle work fine. I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work for me. I tried issuing the draw() function on DataTables but that doesn't fix it either. I'm sure your code is correct.

Comment: I edited my question so you will understand better what I'm doing. I think I only need to convert `newHtml` back to string at this point.

Comment: I was able to get the string value with `.prop('outerHTML')`. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand it well, but you can try

```
var html = '<input value="0" id="someid" color="red" size="large" type="text">';
$(html).attr("color", "black")[0].outerHTML;
    // '<input value="0" id="someid" color="black" size="large" type="text">'
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that outerHTML is not a function.

Comment: @rwkiii Oh true, it worked here because StackExchange adds it as a jQuery extension. Fixed.

Comment: I still get outerHTML is not a function. :S

Comment: I removed the `()` after outerHTML and no longer get the error. I'm still not seeing the attribute getting updated. I'm not sure why it isn't getting changed. I've tried every answer on this page and none are working.

Comment: @rwkiii Can you provide a testcase? I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: I edited my question. When using your answer color attribute doesn't change for some reason. I tried Bojan's answer and the attribute does change, but now I need to convert back to string.

Answer (score 0):

We can parse the string as an element, and then get its ID, and then find that ID in the DOM.

```
var inputfield = $('#' + $('<input value="0" id="someid" color="red" size="large" type="text">').attr('id'));
```

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend you to define two CSS classes, one "red" and one "black". Then just use .addClass() and .removeClass() to get the visual effect changed.

Comment: @Rein the color and size attributes are just examples. I don't need to change CSS at all.